# goormIDE changing default project that terminal loads on

Tags: terminal, ide

I wanted to ask a question about goormIDE, which is very similar in function to c9.io

When I first started on my container, I named my first project `goorm-IDE-test2` in order to learn the node.js language.

However, I since then started work on a subproject, called `myBootcamp`.

Whenever I first load the container, the default path of the first terminal is

```
root@goorm:/workspace/goorm-IDE-test2#
```

and I want to change this so the default should be

```
root@goorm:/workspace/myBootcamp#
```

I've discovered that I can open a separate terminal off the new project, but I can't load `myBootcamp` as the default from the start.

How can I do this, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open [Preference] (type `alt + p`)
2. Go to [Terminal] - [Profile]
3. Add this two lines of shell script at the bottom of the profile

```
alias clear="cd /workspace/[NAME OF SUBPROJECT] && clear"
cd /workspace/[NAME OF SUBPROJECT]
```

4. Click [Apply] then [Close]
5. Done ;)

[image: preference_example]
[image: working_example]

Comment: This only works when I open a new terminal manually or refresh the terminal after I logged on. I would like the first terminal that loads to automatically go to the subproject I want. Right now when I load the container, it still leads me first to `goorm-IDE-test2`

Comment: That's wierd. Just attached an image of an working example. Double check if you edited your terminal profile correctly. (Please assure that you replaced `both [NAME OF SUBPROJECT]` with `myBootcamp`)

Comment: Magic! I was just a bit silly because I replaced my first `SUBPROJECT` with my initial project and then replaced my second `SUBPROJECT` with my intended one that's why! Can I ask just for reference what your terminal code does exactly so that in the future I can do this from memory with understanding! You're a life saver btw!